# Mac style menu in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi i want to create a mac style menu like this http://actionscriptnotes.com/showcase/macmenu/Main.html  in Windows form using C#.

Comment: Try using WPF or Silverlight.

Comment: @setphen776 My question is how to i create the effect shown in the link in my windows form Desktop Application

Comment: @ykatchou : Is there any custom library for this . I want to do it with windows forms only

Comment: I don't think there is a library for that, and even less in winforms. Winforms are old, and absolutely not suitable for such a complex image manipulation and transparency management (transparency in winforms really sucks...). WPF instead, would give you more chances to achive a good result.

Comment: I think you should edit your question to say "dock" instead of "menu".  And the dock isn't supposed to be part of an application, but rather part of the desktop environment.  So you really shouldn't be doing this at all, let alone in winforms.

Comment: Yeah i am aware of the dock feature .But i want a similar effect in my application only. I am sure this could be achieved with some complex set of timing and zoom operations but was just looking around if its already been implemented .

Answer (score 0):

Google 'wpf mac dock'. There are several projects:
[this](http://www.designerwpf.com/2008/12/02/mac-style-button-tray-in-silverlight/), [and that](http://chakkaradeep.wordpress.com/2007/08/15/macdock-updated-to-hold-aero-style/).

Edit - didn't notice you want to use Winforms. As Others said, probably not gonna happen. You can embed a WPF control in Winforms.